# <task:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" /> no longer possible in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Why was the attribute **mode** removed from Spring 3.1 [task xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd)? It's there in 3.0 version, and also the code in Spring 3.1 classes still check for the attribute and activate AspectJ mode is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting! Could be just a bug - the reason I am speculating this to be a bug is because it is still possible to select the mode via `@Configuration` using `@EnableAsync(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`

This answers a part of your question, about why the check for mode is still there in the code - because it is possible through @Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It was a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10177). Fixed in 3.1.4/3.2.1. Use spring-task-3.0.xsd or spring-task-3.2.xsd as workaround.